# uTorrent automatic scheduling program

Tags: windows, home-networking, scheduled-tasks, utorrent, c#

I am using utorrent on a mini "home utorrent server" full time. And when I go to bed, I have to manually set up the bandwith limit to max. And in the morning, I have to set it up to, say, 60% of the max. This is boring and I sometimes forget to do it...

So I want to following : when I boot any PC in my home network (whether its a laptop, my desktop computer or a friend laptop), the utorrent bandwith limit automatically slows down. Keep in mind that I want the utorrent preferences to change based on whether or not I am on a PC at home.

First of all, I didn't find any software or utorrent configuration that does it. So I have though about writing a program (probably in C#) and it goes like this:

I can configure 2 modes: "slow mode" (eg 60% bandwith), and "fast mode" (eg 100% bandwith).
Every minute or so, it scans IP's from 192.168.0.1(included) to 192.168.0.30(more or less). For each of thoses ips, it looks up the related machine name. If, in the range of ips, there is only one machine and it is the utorrent server, set utorrent preferences to "fast mode". If there are more machines, set utorrent preferences to "slow mode". The automatic preferences setup can be made via http api of utorrent.

Before doing it, I want to know if there are more simple approaches to do that. If not, then I want to know if you see something impossible in what I just described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This application may solve your requirements:
http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=73450

Quote from the website:

> This [windows] application can regulate Global upload and download speeds of uTorrent on the basis of Network based, Process based and Time based rules.

- Network based allows you to lower dowload/upload rates wether other ipv4 address are accessible on LAN
- Process based is the same for windows processes
- Time based is the same with periods of time

Comment: you may want to give a more complete explaination of what the link is, what it does, and how it solves the poster's issue. The devil is in the details.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i needed. The "network based regulation" is quite similar to the little program i did.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways i can see this working - router side QOS, with something like DDWRT, and setting torrents to have a lower priority, or some form of traffic shaping - i know of 'trickle' on *nix based systems, and a [traffic shaping option on ddwrt](http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,2845,1934575,00.asp) but i haven't tried out any windows software that does the same - a quick google search seems to suggest they do exist .

If you choose to do it on the windows end you'll then need to work out some way to start the programme - maybe using [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) on the 'other' system to start the traffic shaper on boot.

Comment: Regarding traffic shaping on Windows, I have been using cFosSspeed for several years. It works quite well (I get 15ms latency for gaming with utorrent active without speed limit) and supports some form of sync between PCs. It is however, not free.

Answer (score 2):

> I am using utorrent on a mini "home utorrent server" full time. And when I go to bed, I have to manually set up the bandwith limit to max. And in the morning, I have to set it up to, say, 60% of the max. This is boring and I sometimes forget to do it...

The second part of your question seems to be a rather involved way to work around this manual method.

What's wrong with just using the uTorrent scheduler - it supports four states:

- BitTorrent Enabled, no throttling (green)
- BitTorrent Enabled, throttling (light green) - adjust the throttled speed to 60% of the maximum using the edit boxes down the bottom of the dialog
- BitTorrent Disabled
- Seeding Only

[image: .....]

Comment: The sceduler is the method that works the best for now. But as i said, i want it to be automatic as my rythm of life is not stable... Moreover, i can get an average +-12/24hours full speed a day with the scheduler, and +- 20/24hours i guess with the dynamic method, because it uses the day of time when i'm not on the pc.

Answer (score 0):

utorrent has a WebUI that you can enable. Once it's configured you can access your server from any machine on your LAN through a web browser. This would allow you to manually throttle the Max Bandwidth down or back up. I also use it to check on the progress of torrents I have queued up.

While not fully automatic like you want, but it's pretty simple to set up and without requiring any custom programming. utorrent also has some kind of API that you might want to look into that would in theory allow you to control it programmatically -- not sure if it would work remotely, though.